# browse files on iphone for crash logs

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I want to make a option like a browse window where the contents of iphone data will be displayed and the user can select any file. I know the nsfileManager can be used but I do not know which paths to gets the data contents and how to use nsfilemanager here.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can onlye access the files stored inside your applications-bundle, are you aware of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it. All that you can - make a desktop app for monitoring files on devices. Or use this http://www.i-funbox.com/ Also, if there is any private API to do it (not sure about it), app still will be rejected from appstore. For your own usage i-funbox is pretty enough.

If you just need crash logs - Xcode can help to find them and parse.